# Getting error "org/openqa/selenium/interactions/HasInputDevices"

Tags: java, maven, appium, serenity-bdd

I am trying to build a java framework for Appium. When I run the tests I get following error:

*java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/interactions/HasInputDevices*

I have not added any additional selenium dependency at all. Even if I add selenium-java this error still persists. Below is my pom.xml and runner file:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
    <serenity.version>3.2.5</serenity.version>
    <serenity.cucumber.version>3.2.5</serenity.cucumber.version>
    <cucumber.version>7.3.3</cucumber.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>serenity-reports</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>aggregate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-cucumber</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jeasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>easy-random-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Runner:

```
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import net.serenitybdd.cucumber.CucumberWithSerenity;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = {"src/test/resources/features"},
    glue = {"steps"},
    tags = "@appiumApp and not @ignore",
    stepNotifications = true,
    plugin = {
            "json:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.json"
    }
 )
 public class TestRunner {
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The above problem was solved by using following combination of dependencies:

```
    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-cucumber</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jeasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>easy-random-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```